# Windows command "net use" failed when login with a no password account

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

My experimental network: 2 windows 7 PCs.

When using below commands trying to connect to PC2 (admin account with no password):

```
net use X: \\PC2\c$ /user:PC2\administrator
```

It will get:

```
System error 5 has occurred.
Access is denied.
```

However, if set a password to PC2 admin account, and do below:

```
net use X: \\PC2\c$ /user:PC2\administrator mypwd
```

This will work.

Is it necessary to have the password set to enable windows file sharing?

Comment: Why would you _ever_ want to make a password-less Administrator account _network-accessible_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, blank passwords aren't allowed for network login.  To change this, modify the relevant setting in the Local Security Policy MMC snapin.

`Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only`

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737553(WS.10).aspx) for details.

Comment: This is perfect. However, is there any way to do this in command line? Need put it in script.

Comment: @Stan I haven't used it myself so I can't provide specific guidance, but it looks like [secedit.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/lpe_topnode.mspx?mfr=true) using the `/areas SECURITYPOLICY` flag should do the trick - should be able to export the settings from one system and script the setup of others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty passwords with the following command:

`net use X: \\PC2\c$ /user:PC2\administrator ""`

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

```
net use X: \\PC2\c$ /user:PC2\administrator ""
```

works really well

you might need to run:

```
net use X: \\PC2\c$ /delete
```

first

Comment: I didn't have the reputation points to comment on the previous answer so I added this answer to thank the original poster for something that is really useful.